# How are primary keys specified with DynamoDB.DocumentClient for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I've been reading a lot of documentation, specifically for `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`, and I'm trying to figure out how I create a Table / DocumentClient with a specific primary key, like `id`. My understanding is that primary keys are required, and that "secondary indexes" are nested attributes, but I don't see any constructor params for actually specifying that `id` will be the primary key.

How can I specify that `id` should be a Table / DocumentClient's primary key?

---

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html

> Note
>   The primary key is required. This code adds an item that has a primary key (year, title) and info attributes. The info attribute stores sample JSON that provides more information about the movie.

Comment: I didnt understand anything about the question. Secondary indexes are nested attributes?? Not at all!! What do you mean? Document client's nodejs api really obvious, you just specify `key` attribute for it. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property Is this what you ask ?

Comment: @CanSahin Sorry, it was a bit vague

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I didn't realize the schema for creating the table was so intricate. Through trial and error with local DynamoDB, it told me that AttributeDefinitions must exist for the KeySchema. This key schema is what designates the "primary" key names, and the types are in a completely separate field.

The constructor object DOES NOT populate the table, it only sets up the initial partition (primary?) key and optional sort key, which would form a composite key.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'
});

var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var awaitTable = db.describeTable({ TableName: 'app-content' }).promise();

awaitTable.catch(e => {
    if (e.statusCode === 400) {

        return db.createTable({
            TableName: 'app-content',
            KeySchema: [
                { 'AttributeName' : 'fooPartitionKeyName', 'KeyType' : 'HASH' },
                { 'AttributeName' : 'barSortKeyName', 'KeyType' : 'RANGE' }
            ],
            AttributeDefinitions: [
                { 'AttributeName' : 'fooPartitionKeyName', 'AttributeType' : 'S' },
                { 'AttributeName' : 'barSortKeyName', 'AttributeType' : 'S' }
            ],
            ProvisionedThroughput: {
                ReadCapacityUnits: 5,
                WriteCapacityUnits: 5,
            },
        }).promise();

    } else { return Promise.reject('Unknown error fetching table.') }

}).then(table => {
    console.log('table!', table);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
KeySchema: [
    {
      AttributeName: 'ID',
      KeyType: 'HASH'
},
```

This should work right?